# How to add custom/extra attributes to Mediawiki links?

Tags: html, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I'm creating template on a *personal wiki* and I want some of the links to have custom attributes (e.g. `rel`, `class`, etc.).

### Using HTML Syntax

I tried to put it as HTML code, but it's then escaped:

```
<a href="#{{{atelier-id|ex:atelier-id}}}" class="pilcrow">¶</a>
<a href="{{{auteur_url|ex:giroll.org/}}}" rel="author">{{{auteur|ex:auteur}}}</a>
```

### Using Wiki Syntax

Then I tried using a wiki syntax, but still no good

```
[[#{{{atelier-id|ex:atelier-id}}}"|¶|pilcrow]]
```

### Question

This seems trivial but I don't find any information on [Help:Links](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aLinks#External_links) page.

So how should I do to add extra attributes to my links ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MediaWiki has no built in way to add link attributes, however there are at least two extensions that provide that functionality. You could try:

- [Extension:Link Attributes](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLink_Attributes)
- [Extension:LinkAttributes](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLinkAttributes)

Comment: what about HTML syntax does it escape `<a>` tag ?

Comment: Yes, unless you set [$wgRawHtml](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRawHtml) to true in `LocalSettings.php` (which is a dangerous thing to do) it does escape everything except for [a few allowed tags](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:HTML_in_wikitext#Permitted_HTML)

Comment: What Extension:LinkAttributes need (some more tests or colaborations?) to be a  stable release?

Comment: @PeterKrauss An extra pair of eyes, and some testing, I belive! :-)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried creating a class in Mediawiki:Common.css that adds the desired attributes to `<a>` tags? Mediawiki doesn't allow raw anchor tags in the code, but wikilinks are still converted to anchor tags when the page is rendered. IF you do something like this:

```
.class a:link,
.class a:visited,
.class a:active,
.class a:hover {
    css: some css;
}
```

then you can wrap your link in the desired class, e.g. `<span class="class">[[link]]</span>`, and have the attributes applied automatically. You should be able to invoke javascript in this way as well.

Comment: I would like to extends wiki syntax not write extra HTML around the wiki syntax

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this by wrapping your links in a span with an id and adding a CSS selector for that id's a elements

In your article:

```
<span id="link-wrapper">[[YourLink]]</span>
```

In your CSS:

```
#link-wrapper a
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

I don't think I can imagine a situation where that won't suffice. There's plenty of other workarounds I can think of, let me know if this one won't do.

Comment: I'm not looking to style but add semantic/accessibility to my content

Comment: Well then add a span with custom attributes <span anything="value">[[YourLink]]</span>. MediaWiki doesn't restrict attributes, it only restricts some tags. If you really need to use the <a> tag you can set $wgRawHtml in your /LocalSettings.php to true. You should however strip all usergroups except for your own usergroup of any rights then.